# Mysql variables and loops

Tags: mysql, loops, variables

I write mysql query. I need get diff between 2 tables insert that diff in 3th and update data in 4th. I have that problem? when i try to update in my db updates only last value.

```
INSERT INTO requests_files_rel 
(SELECT @cnt:=COUNT(id_request) @id_req:=id_request,@id_file:=id_file
     FROM requests_mandates_rel WHERE id_file NOT IN (SELECT id_file FROM requests_files_rel));  
UPDATE files_main SET id_patient = (SELECT @id_patient:=id_patient FROM requests_main
    WHERE id_request=@id_req) 
    WHERE id_file IN (@id_file);
```

Never work with that queries. Maby someone can show me way to resolve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE files_main fm
    SET fm.id_patient = 
    (
        SELECT id_patient
        FROM requests_main rm
        INNER JOIN requests_mandates_rel rmr ON rm.id_request = rmr.id_request
        WHERE fm.id_file = rmr.id_file
    )
    WHERE fm.id_file IN 
       (
           SELECT id_file
           FROM requests_mandates_rel 
           WHERE id_file NOT IN 
              (
                  SELECT id_file 
                  FROM requests_files_rel
               )
       );

INSERT INTO requests_files_rel (id_request, id_file)
(   
    SELECT id_request, id_file
    FROM requests_mandates_rel 
    WHERE id_file NOT IN 
       (
           SELECT id_file 
           FROM requests_files_rel
       )
);
```

Here is my end variant all works fine, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the order like so

```
SELECT COUNT(id_request) INTO @cnt
```

NOTE: you can only store one value inside a variable. so in your question you say that  you are only getting the last value updated.. thats probably because you have an AGGREGATE COUNT() which combines all rows into one.. unless you use a group by... your variables aren't going to work with multiple rows of data though...

if you want to use variables for this operation then you will need to make a few changes..

```
SELECT COUNT(id_request) as num_req , id_request, id_file
FROM requests_mandates_rel 
WHERE id_file NOT IN (SELECT id_file FROM requests_files_rel)
GROUP BY id_file
```

take this select which will give the count per file and then do this with it.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(num_req) INTO @cnt, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(id_request) INTO @id_req, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(id_file) INTO @id_file
FROM
(   SELECT COUNT(id_request) as num_req , id_request, id_file
    FROM requests_mandates_rel 
    WHERE id_file NOT IN (SELECT id_file FROM requests_files_rel)
    GROUP BY id_file
)t
```

now to use the concated values you have to use FIND_IN_SET()

```
UPDATE files_main fm, 
    (   SELECT id_patient
        FROM requests_main
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_request, @id_req) > 0
    ) t
    SET fm.id_patient = t.id_patient
    WHERE fm.id_file IN (@id_file);
```

---

im curious if you should be using variables in the first place... couldn't you just do the query like this?

```
INSERT INTO requests_files_rel (column_for_count, column_for_requestid, column_for_fileid)
(   SELECT COUNT(id_request), id_request, id_file
    FROM requests_mandates_rel 
    WHERE id_file NOT IN (SELECT id_file FROM requests_files_rel)
);

UPDATE files_main fm, 
    (   SELECT id_patient
        FROM requests_main
        WHERE id_request IN
        (   SELECT id_request
            FROM requests_mandates_rel 
            WHERE id_file NOT IN (SELECT id_file FROM requests_files_rel)
        )
    ) t
    SET fm.id_patient = t.id_patient
    WHERE fm.id_file IN (@id_file);
```

Comment: When i run fixed code i have an error. Maby Mysql have functions for working with loops? I cant save array to Mysql variable?

Comment: @kickman2l look at the edits I made you cannot save an array to a mysql variable it holds only one scalar value... so you have to combine rows into one with a group_concat... and then use find_in_set() to pull them out of that comma separated list.

Comment: will try some later, very big database need time to source it back. Also thanks.

Comment: I change query and get another problem. When i try to use condition WHERE IN (@id_file) mysql takes only 1st value from concated value, if i enter that values manualy query works nice.

Comment: @kickman2l you can select them again.. i was just trying to cut down on overhead.. just change the `@id_file` to a select for those specific files. or even better put it in a temporary table that way you only have to do it once :)